# How to solve class not found

Tags: laravel-5.3

I have made custom classes in App\foldername, following are 2 classes. Child classes can be many.

```
App\foldername\ChildCls
App\foldername\MyMainCls
```

ChildCls.php

```
namespace App\foldername;

class ChildCls {

}
```

MyMainCls.php

```
namespace App\foldername;

class MyMainCls{
   function validateGroupValues($groupname){
      //here $groupname will be class name that is "ChildCls" that will be dynamically loaded         

      $ob = new $groupname();

}
}
```

In Controller

```
use App\Diamond_Search\MyMainCls;

class MySearchController extends Controller
{
   $ob = new MyMainCls();
   $ob->validateGroupValues('test');
}
```

But I am getting following error

> Class 'ChildCls' not found

If I statically use $ob = new \App\foldername\ChildCls then it works fine but I can't mention it statically because there will be many child classes that I have to call dynamically.

So what can be the possible solutions in this case?

Comment: `$clsname = "\App\foldername\$groupname"; new $clsname()`?

Answer (score 0):

put this next to the namespace.

```
use App\foldername\ChildCls;
```